# Compare list against other list and modify

Tags: c#

Supposed that I have these classes

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MySubject> MySubjects  { get; set; }
}

public class MySubject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Schedule { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
}
```

sample data

```
var subjects = new List<Subject>()
    {
        new Subject(){ Id = 1, Category = "Mathematics", Type = "Algebra" },
        new Subject(){ Id = 2, Category = "Computer Science", Type = "Pascal" }
    };

var student = new Student() 
        { Id = 1, MySubjects = new List<MySubject>() { 
            new MySubject() {Id = 1, Category = "Mathematics", Type = "Algebra" },
            new MySubject() {Id = 3, Category = "Mathematics", Type = "Trigonometry"},
         }
        };

//TODO: Update list here
student.MySubjects.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}\t", i.Id, i.Category, i.Type));
```

the above line of code returns

1-Mathematics-Algebra
3-Mathematics-Trigonometry

which is incorrect. I need to return this

1-Mathematics-Algebra
2-Computer Science-Pascal

Basically I would like to modify and iterate the student.MySubjects and check its contents against subjects.

I would like to remove the subjects (3-Mathematics-Trigonometry) that are not present in the subjects and also ADD subjects that are missing (2-Computer Science-Pascal).

Can you suggest an efficient way to do this by searching/comparing using Category + Type?

Comment: why is MySuject a different type?

Comment: yes in reality its different type. i had to simplify my example. thanks

Comment: Try with [`List.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall),  see [`this example`](https://rextester.com/GYMQB99471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below.

```
// Remove those subjects which are not present in subjects list
student.MySubjects.RemoveAll(x => !subjects.Any(y => y.Category == x.Category && y.Type == x.Type));

// Retrieve list of subjects which are not added in students.MySubjects
var mySubjectsToAdd = subjects.Where(x => !student.MySubjects.Any(y => y.Category == x.Category && y.Type == x.Type))
                            .Select(x => new MySubject() {
                                Id = x.Id,
                                Category = x.Category,
                                Type = x.Type
                            }).ToList();

// If mySubjectsToAdd has any value then add it into student.MySubjects
if (mySubjectsToAdd.Any()) 
{
    student.MySubjects.AddRange(mySubjectsToAdd);
}

student.MySubjects.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}\t", i.Id, i.Category, i.Type));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// make an inner join based on mutual values to filter out wrong subjects.
var filteredList = 
        from mySubject in student.MySubjects
        join subject in subjects
        on new { mySubject.Category, mySubject.Type }
        equals new { subject.Category, subject.Type }
        select new MySubject { Id = mySubject.Id, Category = mySubject.Category, Type = mySubject.Type };

// make a left outer join to find absent subjects.
var absentList =
    from subject in subjects
    join mySubject in filteredList
    on new { subject.Category, subject.Type }
    equals new { mySubject.Category, mySubject.Type } into sm
    from s in sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where s == null
    select new MySubject { Id = subject.Id, Category = subject.Category, Type = subject.Type };

student.MySubjects = filteredList.ToList();
student.MySubjects.AddRange(absentList.ToList());
```